# Symfony2 form: repated type and his rendering in twig

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I have a a form and one of the fields is :

```
$builder->add('password', 'repeated', array(
    'type' => 'password',
    'invalid_message' => 'The password fields must match.',
    'options' => array('attr' => array('class' => 'password-field')),
    'required' => true,
    'first_options'  => array('label' => 'Password'),
    'second_options' => array('label' => 'Confirm Password'),
));
```

Everything is fine here, except for the form rendering. I am used to render the form in the twig file this way:

```
 <table style="width:500px; padding:30px">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    {{ form_label(form.email) }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ form_widget(form.email, { 'attr': {'size': 30} }) }}
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    {{ form_label(form.password.first) }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ form_row(form.password.first, { 'attr': {'size': 30} }) }}
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    {{ form_label(form.password.second) }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ form_row(form.password.second, { 'attr': {'size': 30} }) }}
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
....
....
```

The problem is that for the repated type, the label is duplicated: see attached image.

Do you know how to resolve this?

Thank you in advance.[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The labels are appearing twice as a result of outputting the password controls using form_row() rather than form_widget(). The form_row() method outputs the field errors, label and widget all in one go. If you want to output the field errors yourself you can use e.g. form_errors(form.password.first).